# Laravel Fortify validation errors not working

Tags: php, laravel, fortify

I'm trying Fortify since one week now and I'm stuck on the same problem at two level.

The problem is when I try to update user password, it doesn't show me validation errors (I mean, when for test purpose I leave fields blank).

The same thing when I try to update user informations (name, email... when I leave them blank for test purpose).

Of course I tried to iterate the $errors variable to display errors message on my views but nothing. I also tried with the @error blade directive but nothing too.

Here's my update password view where I perform an PUT submit to the user-password.update route defined by Fortify

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check your User model in App\Models\User if the password is set in the fillable property

Comment: Yeah of course, it's set in the fillable properties, the thing is about the validation, it looks like it doesn't works

Comment: You can always check by putting  dd() or info() before calling the Validator to check if the controller is hit with the required data. Just check if the form data is received by the validator inside your controller.And if you are using Request Object to handle the form data then make sure you inject the request object(eg. ChangePasswordRequest $changePasswordRequest) into the method and not the regular request( eg. Request $request).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code in your blade

```
@if ($errors->updatePassword->any())
     <ul>
         @foreach($errors->updatePassword->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
         @endforeach
     </ul>
@endif
```

This "$errors->updatePassword" is the Bag Name which will be found in "app/Actions/Fortify/UpdateUserPassword.php"

Comment: Thanks !! It working now by usine this method 

Comment: Do you know how can I find the error message bag name for login errors

Answer (score 1):

its work

```
@if ($errors->updatePassword->any())
 <ul>
     @foreach($errors->updatePassword->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
     @endforeach
 </ul>
@endif
```

or you can change method `validateWithBag('updatePassword')` in "app/Actions/Fortify/UpdateUserPassword.php" with `validate()`

Comment: What's the difference between yours and @MNI Noyon's answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, @MNI Noyon

```
@if( $errors->confirmTwoFactorAuthentication->any() )
<div class="mb-3">
    <ul>
        @foreach( $errors->confirmTwoFactorAuthentication->all() as $error )
            <li class="text-red-500 text-xs" >{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

And to @arul project's point, I would have to update `vendor/fortify/src/Actions/ConfirmTwoFactorAuthenticate.php` from

```
 ])->errorBag('confirmTwoFactorAuthentication');
```

to

```
 ])->validate();
```

if I wanted to access the errors via `$errors->any()`. But please correct me if I am wrong.